# Evaluation of multiples 'IN' Expressions in 'WHERE' clauses in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, where-clause, evaluation

*Updating by `@Cesar`'s request. Hope I understood what you want, if not, please revert. Quassnoi.*

If I make an `SQL` query like this: `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE b IN (2, 7) AND c IN (3, 9)`, can I assume that `MySQL` will match only pairs from elements with same number in each list?

That is, `(2, 3)`, `(7, 9)`, ...?

For example, suppose we have a table like this:

```
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |    PK    |     b    |     c    |
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |     1    |     2    |     3    |
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |     2    |     5    |     4    |
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |     3    |     7    |     9    |
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |     4    |     7    |     4    |
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |     5    |     2    |     9    |
 +----------+----------+----------+
```

Is it correct to assume that the *only* rows returned are `1` and `3` (and not `5`)?

Comment: you'd better change "c IN(4,4)" in your example for clarification.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> ```
> SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE b IN(5,7) AND c IN(4,4)
> ```

This query will return rows, where `b` is either `5` or `7`, AND `c` is `4`.

What do you mean by "evaluation in pairs?"

**Update:**

I'll add one more row to the sample:

```
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |    PK    |     b    |     c    |
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |     1    |     2    |     3    |
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |     2    |     5    |     4    |
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |     3    |     7    |     9    |
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |     4    |     7    |     4    |
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |     5    |     2    |     9    |
 +----------+----------+----------+
```

If you want to match the whole sets, you can use this syntax:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table_name
WHERE   (b, c) IN ((2, 3), (7, 9))
```

This means: "return all rows where `b` is `2` and `c` is `3` at the same time, OR `b` is `7` and `с` is `9` at the same time."

In the example above, this query will return rows `1` and `3`

But if you rewrite this query the other way around, like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table_name
WHERE   b IN (2, 7)
        AND c IN (3, 9)
```

, this will mean "return all rows where `b` is either `2` or `7`, AND `c` is either `3` or `9`).

This will return rows `1`, `3` and `5`, since row `5` satisfies the condition for the second query but not for the first one.

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm trying to do (the whole sets thing), only that i'm not a english speaker
and i guess i didn't make myself clear
If somebody could edit the question to reflect what i'm looking for, please feel free to do it.

Answer (score 5):

The return of rows 2 & 4 is correct, though your choice of (4,4) can make it a little more confusing, as it is redundant.  The AND means that the row must satisfy both your conditions to be true.  If the query had `WHERE b IN(5,7) AND c IN(4,9)`, you would get rows 2, 3, and 4 returned.

If you think of it in pairs, you need to have all the combinations.  e.g., `b IN(5,7) AND c IN(4,9)` would yield (5,4), (5,9), (7,4), and (7,9) as possible combinations that would work, and NOT just (5,4) and (7,9)

Answer (score 5):

You can evaluate each condition in order, it might give you a better idea on what is happening here. Your query states that all values should be selected where b is either 5 or 7 and c is 4, so let's reduce the table using first condition (`b IN (5,7)`):

```
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |    PK    |     b    |     c    |
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |     1    |     2    |     3    | < No match
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |     2    |     5    |     4    | < Match
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |     3    |     7    |     9    | < Match
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |     4    |     7    |     4    | < Match
 +----------+----------+----------+
```

Now, let's evaluate the next condition, both must be true in order for a row to be selected (`c IN (4,4)`, hich is essentially the same as `c = 4`):

```
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |    PK    |     b    |     c    |
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |     2    |     5    |     4    | < Match
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |     3    |     7    |     9    | < No match
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |     4    |     7    |     4    | < Match
 +----------+----------+----------+
```

Everything else is valid:

```
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |    PK    |     b    |     c    |
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |     2    |     5    |     4    |
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |     4    |     7    |     4    |
 +----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe you are correct.

Effectively, 'IN' can be considered shorthand for (b = 5 OR b = 7).  This is NOT how it works 'under the hood', but it is an easy way to think of it.

For large tables, multiple 'IN' clauses will cause performance issues.

EDIT:

The above poster is correct, c IN (4, 4) is pointless.  You could just as easily say 'AND c = 4'.

If you convert the clauses to their logical equivalents, you see why:

SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (b = 5 OR b = 7) AND (c = 4 OR c = 4)

Comment: He's correct that his query will return rows 2 and 4 but not for the reason he thinks.

Comment: Ah, just got what he meant by 'evaluation in pairs' and clarified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not exactly illustrate your question, but *multiple IN clauses are not related to one another; they are evaluated in sequence like any other WHERE clause*.

Thus, the following query

```
SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE b IN(5,7) AND c IN(4,8)
```

will match any of the following:

```
b  c
----
5  4
5  8
7  4
7  8
```

---

`IN` can be considered shorthand for or-separated comparisons. This means the previous query can also be written as (the mechanics are slightly different, but the concept is the same):

```
SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE (b = 5 OR b = 7) AND (c = 4 OR c = 8)
```

---

So, in your example, yes, the only rows returned are 2 and 4. But it is not quite for the reason you suppose.