# Filter data based on multiple rows SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is probably as simple SQL query. I'm finding it little tricky, as it's been a while I've written SQL.

```
ID  NAME        VALUE
--- ------      -------
1   Country     Brazil
1   Country     India
2   Country     US
2   EmpLevel    1
3   EmpLevel    3
```

Pseudo Query:

```
Select * 
from table_name 
where (country = US or country = Brazil) 
  and (Employee_level = 1 or Employee_level = 3)
```

This query should return

```
 ID NAME        VALUE
 ---    ------      -------
 2      Country      US
 2      EmpLevel     1
```

(As record with ID - 2 has Country as 'US' and EmpLevel  '1')

I went through couple SO posts as well.

[Multiple row SQL Where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488371/multiple-row-sql-where-clause])

[SQL subselect filtering based on multiple sub-rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789990/sql-subselect-filtering-based-on-multiple-sub-rows)

[Evaluation of multiples 'IN' Expressions in 'WHERE' clauses in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194289/evaluation-of-multiples-in-expressions-in-where-clauses-in-mysql?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're expected results for the `country` should be `US` instead of `Brazil`.  Here's one option using a `join` with `conditional aggregation`:

```
select y.* 
from yourtable y join (
  select id
  from yourtable
  group by id
  having max(case when name = 'Country' then value end) in ('US','Brazil') and
         max(case when name = 'EmpLevel' then value end) in ('1','3')
) y2 on y.id = y2.id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4318/1)

Comment: Bit late, :) Yes, Updated the question as per the comment